# Folder (inode/directory) some contents unreadable

Tags: 18.04

At Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS I checked with files and got this:

```
Name: /
Type: Folder(inode/directory)
Contents: 403,420 items, totalling 124.9 GB
(some contents unreadable)

128.0 GB used
94.7 GB free
Total capacity: 234.6 GB
Filesystem type: ext3/ext4
```

How can I fix some contents unreadable ?

Comment: Sometimes that message is related to access permissions. Can you verify that the location is properly accessible to the account you’re using?

Comment: I got 2 users at the computer, myself and root, it is unreadable for root and myself.

Comment: Do you know which items are unreadable? If it’s for locations that are using a `tmpfs` file system or are mounted with a `loop`, then it’s not an issue 

Comment: Actually I don't know which files are unreadable, is there an option to figure out which files are unreadable ?